# WhizzyTeX and PDF Tools in Emacs on macOS

Tags: emacs

I am now using the package `whizzytex.el` for real-time incremental previewing of LaTeX code in Emacs, and I encounter a difficulty when I want to change the previewer type from `advi` to `pdf-tools`.

I follow the method described on this website `https://email.esm.psu.edu/pipermail/macosx-tex/2005-April/014597.html` to modify some functions and their values in the shell script `whizzytex`.

The modifications are as follows:

- In the line 877 or thereabouts, I find a passage that looks like this:

```
 {
   $VIEWCOMMAND "$WHIZZYVIEW" "$CLIENTVIEW" <&3 2>"$OUTPUT"/view &
 echo $! >> "$TMP"/pids
 ID=$!
   ......
```

I modify this passage to:

```
 cp WHIZZYVIEW.pdf 
   $VIEWCOMMAND "WHIZZYOUT.pdf" "$CLIENTVIEW" <&3 2>"$OUTPUT"/view &
 echo $! >> "$TMP"/pids
 ID=$!
   ......
```

- In the line 902 or thereabouts, there is a function `xpdfreload`, I comment out this function and modify it to become the following form:

```
xpdfreload () {
cp $WHIZZYOUT.$VIEW $WHIZZYOUT.pdf
}
```

- In the line 974 or thereabouts, there comes the function `whole`. Below the line `echo '<Whole document updated>'` I add the following line:

```
cp $WHIZZYOUT.$VIEW $WHIZZYOUT.pdf
```

- In the line 1016 or thereabouts, there comes the function `duplex`. I comment out the line `$VIEWCOMMAND $NAMEVIEW &` and replace it with `$VIEWCOMMAND $NAMEOUT.pdf &`.

Finally, in the first line of the LaTeX document preamble I add a File-based configuration declaration as follows:

```
%; whizzy section -pdf "/usr/local/share/whizzytex/epdfinfo" -initex "pdflatex -ini" -latex pdflatex
```

When I reopen Emacs and want to load up `whizzytex` with `M-x whizzytex-mode` it does NOT work but displaying some indications such as `Mode switched off externally` in the bottom minibuffer.

However, I can use the specific viewer `advi` for previewing combined with `whizzytex mode`. What makes me want to change the previewer is that the resolution of `advi` under `X11` window is poor and I can't scroll up and down in the previewing region of `advi`, so I want to switch to `pdf-tools` as my new previewer.

I have carefully scrutinized the `whizzytex` manual, but it still hasn't solved the problem I'm struggling for. I have tried to modify the shell script `whizzytex` in `/usr/local/bin` as mentioned above, and I would like to realize the purpose of previewing in `whizzytex mode` with `PDF Tools`. Please help me out a bit, any hints or suggestions will be quite appreciated.